# Multivariate Hypergeometric Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I think my problem is unique in that it hasn't been posed here.

Starting with a simple case to which I think I have an answer:
I have 11 cards, 3 of which are bad.  These cards are used in a game where on a turn a card is drawn.  If it's one of the 3 bad cards nothing happens, but if it's the second bad card, you lose.  You have the option after a card is drawn to stop.  I want to know the probability of losing by a particular turn.  This seems like a straightforward application of the hypergeometric distribution cumulative distribution function.

$\frac{\binom{3}{2} \binom{8}{n-2} + \binom{3}{3} \binom{8}{n-3}}{\binom{11}{n}}$  is the answer I think I'm looking for.

To make things more complicated:
I again have 11 cards.  There are now two types of bad cards, 6 total bad cards.  The remaining 5 cards are benign .  Similar to before if the card drawn is bad AND that same type of bad card is drawn, you lose.  I again want to know the probability of losing by a particular turn.  I think this is an application of a multivariate hypergeometric distribution CDF but now I'm not sure.

I've calculated what I think the probabilities are on each turn for the two scenarios I've described, plus the scenario in which there are three types of bad cards.  I didn't use a hypergeometric distribution to do it, I used a brute force technique.  It was rather labor-intensive so I've been trying to come up with an elegant solution, but I'm failing.

1badtype: {0% 5.455% 15.152% 27.879% 42.424% 57.576% 72.121% 84.848% 94.545% 100% 100%}
2badtype: {0% 10.909% 30.303% 53.030% 73.810% 88.961% 97.273% 100% 100% 100% 100%}
3badtype: {0% 16.364% 45.455% 75% 93.701% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%}

For reference this is a simplified version of the game Diamat.

EDIT:
I think the "2badtype" case has the solution as
$$\frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{3}\binom{5}{n-6}+2\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{n-5}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{n-4}+2\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{n-4}+2\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{0}\binom{5}{n-3}+2\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{n-3}+2\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{0}\binom{5}{n-2}}{\binom{11}{n}}$$

This formula matches my previous brute force solution, so that makes me confident.  There's still a possibility that both of my approaches are wrong, but when two separate methods yield the same results it's promising.

I took a bit of a intuitive approach to this, so I'm slightly closer to a general formula, but not quite there yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For the future you might consider formatting the mathematics of your posts using this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula I've come up with, and it appears to work for my purposes.

$$1-\frac{\sum_{j_i}^{k_i-1}{\prod_i^c{\binom{K_i}{j_i}\binom{N-\sum{K}}{n-\sum{j}}}}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

It calculates the same probabilities that I posted in my original question.